# Thread Safety for Dependency Injections

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, jvm

I would like to make use of dependency injections at different threads whilst imploring safety.

Lemme start with the basics and I reference all the way unto Java basics: Stack and the Heap. The stack is a LIFO data structure that stores primitive data types and references whereas the Heap stores the Objects that will be referenced. These are the basics that Java programs run on irrespective of the means that they were made be it Spring or other frameworks. Spring support dependency injections for example:

`@Autowired MyClass myClass;`
These injections live in the application context and irrespective of which class you call them from, they will refer to the same object. At the end of the day, there's a reference and an object. One lives on the stack the other on the heap. My question is: in the event of multi-threading, will be there safety for these dependency injections? Please expound in the context of reference and object irrespective of whether the answer is yes or no.

Comment: If you aren't storing mutable state at the instance level there is nothing that isn't thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Your DI framework will handle the construction of those dependencies. No need to worry about that. As for the implementation of those services, if you are sharing them across threads, you will need to make sure they are thread safe. One easy way to accomplish that, is to simply not have any mutable state.